# How can I solve this Bessel's Differential Equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, summation, bessel-functions

This is the equation:

$$x^2 (x-5)^2y''+4xy'+(x^2-25)y=0$$

My problem is that I didn't know what to do with $(x-5)^2$, if I divided the equation by this value, it will no longer be Bessel's equation.

Any suggestions or help?

is it possible to find the indical equation using the usual fomula $$r^2+[P(0)-1]+Q(0)=0$$ , or since its not bessel i cant use it ?

Comment: You may find the solutions given by power series, but this will probably not provide every solutions, because the coefficient of $y''$ vanishes at $0$. You may have maximal solutions on $]0,+\infty[$ or $]-\infty,0[$.

Comment: how can i find the indical equation ? @ Christophe Leuridan

Comment: Consider a power series $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $R>0$. Compute $x^2(x-5)^2f''(x)+4xf'(x)+(x^2-25)f(x)$ to get a power series $\sum b_n x^n$ (with radius of convergence at least $R$). Each $b_n$ will be a function of $a_{n-2}, a_{n-1}, a_n$ and $n$. Then $f$ is solution if and only if all $b_n$ are null.

Answer (score 2):

It's not Bessel's equation.  Maple solves it using Heun functions.
$$y \! \left(x \right) = 
c_{1} x^{\frac{21}{50}+\frac{\sqrt{2941}}{50}} \left(x -5\right)^{\frac{2}{25}-\frac{\sqrt{2941}}{50}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}} \mathit{HeunC}\! \left(\frac{4}{25}, i \sqrt{3}, \frac{\sqrt{2941}}{25}, -\frac{108}{625}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{5}{x -5}\right)+c_{2} x^{\frac{21}{50}+\frac{\sqrt{2941}}{50}} \left(x -5\right)^{\frac{2}{25}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2941}}{50}} \mathit{HeunC}\! \left(\frac{4}{25}, -i \sqrt{3}, \frac{\sqrt{2941}}{25}, -\frac{108}{625}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{5}{x -5}\right)
$$

If you're looking for series solutions, you might start by finding the indicial equation.

Comment: This is better than Mathematica does: all you get from it is a DifferentialRoot object. (Which basically amounts to "this is the thing which solves your equation" rather than anything symbolic.)

Comment: @Robert Israel , yes thats what am struggling to fing , the indical equation plus the series solution... is it posibble to find the indical equation using the usual formala $$r^2+[P(0)-1]+Q(0)=0$$?

Comment: Write your equation as $a(x)y'' + b(x) y' + c(x) y = 0$.  If $xb(x)/a(x)$ and $x^2 c(x)/a(x)$ have finite limits $p$ and $q$ respecively as $x \to 0$, it has a regular singular point at $x=0$; the indicial equation is then $r^2 + (p-1) r + q = 0$.